# aws firehose to s3 bucket partitioning name like year=YYYY, month=MM, day=MM, hour=HH

Tags: amazon-s3, partition, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Currently, AWS Firehose has a default partitioning feature to return  the data into S3 with this following partitioned format of folders:
YYYY/MM/DD/HH => `e.g: 2017/10/26/18`

But, I would like to make it like this:

`Year=2017/Month=10/Day=26/Hour=18`

Is there a way to make the default way to be like above in firehose?

I was trying to trigger a SNS topic to invoke a lambda to change the names to be year=yyyy, month=mm, etc, but the problem is that firehose takes some time to create those default partitioned folders. So I am not too sure how to achieve this without possible conflicts - lambda calls before folder has been created.

It would be best if there is an `AWS` way to handle this, which would be an ideal - which I have not found it yet.

Any suggestion would be appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Dynamic Partitioning, you can use the following expression in the `S3 bucket prefix` on the Kinesis Firehose configuration:

`input/kinesis-realtime/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/`

Answer (score -1):

use s3 prefix option as 'year=!{timestamp:YYYY}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/' to get your folder structure as Year=2017/Month=10/Day=26/Hour=18